# How to get only a content of a variable without extra info when Write-Output in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm reading this XML (this is a small sample):

```
  <gameList>
      <game id="39873" source="screenscraper.fr">
          <path>./1941.zip</path>
          <name>1941 - Counter Attack</name>
          <desc>asdasdasd</desc>
          <image>./images/1941-image.png</image>
          <rating>0.8</rating>
          <releasedate>19900101T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Capcom</developer>
          <publisher>Capcom</publisher>
          <genre>Shoot'em up</genre>
          <players>2</players>
          <video>./videos/1941-video.mp4</video>
      </game>
```

and using this script:

```
$input = "gamelist.xml"
$xml = ( Select-Xml -Path $input -XPath / ).Node
$rom = $xml.selectSingleNode('//game/path[contains(text(),"1941")]')

Write $rom
```

I was expecting as a result only `./1941.zip`

But what I have is:

```
#text
-----
./1941.zip
```

My intention with this code is to use a variable instead of "1941", but I think before to do that I need to figure out how to get only the content of `$rom`.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `Write-Output $rom.#text`

Comment: Quick answer: `$rom.#text` should give you the expected output.
`$rom | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"`, too.

Comment: Write-Output $rom.#text doesn't work.
It returns an error:
At line:5 char:19
+ Write-Output $rom.#text
+                   ~
Missing property name after reference operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingPropertyName

Comment: But $rom | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text" works fine. Thanks guys!